# How is it possible that selecting first after GroupBy on a DataTable does not return one value for every group?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get one row per `id` from a DataTable, and I do not care which row I take. The same `id` can exist on several rows in the table.

Here's the expression that's giving me trouble:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i.Field<int>("id")).Select(i => i.First())
```

Running just this section `dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i.Field<int>("id")` correctly gives me a result of 22 groupings for my DataTable. (I have 22 ids with data in this table)

However, when adding on the `.Select(i => i.First())`, I am only seeing 10 data rows.

To me this doesn't seem to make any sense. If the `GroupBy` function managed to find 22 distinct `id` values, I would expect this logic to grab one of each.

My only other thought is that maybe it's just a weird side effect of viewing this data through a watch in Visual Studio rather than assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think it's just weird side effects of viewing the data in a watch, which can happen with LINQ statements, then split it out into

```cs
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i.Field<int>("id")).ToList();
var firstOfGroups = groups.Select(i => i.First()).ToList();
```

and then look at `groups` and `firstOfGroups` in the debugger. Temporarily evaluating items with `.ToList()` can help a lot with viewing things in the debugger.

Comment: Turns out it was due to the watch. Thank you, this is resolved now

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, can double check the count of each group items

`.Select(g=>new { k = g.Key, c = g.Count() })`